# Returning Distinct Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, distinct, date

Morning

I am trying to return the distinct dates of an outcome by a unique identifer.

For example:

```
ID|Date
1 | 2011-10-01 23:57:59
1 | 2011-10-01 23:58:59
1 | 2010-10-01 23:59:59
2 | 2010-09-01 23:59:59
2 | 2010-09-01 23:58:29
3 | 2010-09-01 23:58:39
3 | 2010-10-01 23:59:14
3 | 2010-10-01 23:59:36
```

The times are not important just the dates. So for example on ID 1 I can't do a distinct on the ID as that would return only one of my dates. So I would want to return:

```
1|2011-10-01
1|2010-10-01
```

I Have tried the following query:

```
Drop Table #Temp

select Distinct DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(DD,0, Date),0) as DateOnly
,ID
Into #Temp
From Table

Select Distinct (Date)
,ID
From #Temp
```

I am getting the following results however:

```
ID|Date
1 | 2011-10-01 00:00:00
1 | 2011-10-01 00:00:00
1 | 2010-10-01 00:00:00
```

I'm new to SQL so apologies I may have made a glaring mistake. I have got so far by searching through the previously asked questions.

As always any help and pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the T-SQL `convert` function to extract the Date.

Try

```
CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

so, in your case, do

```
Drop Table #Temp

select Distinct CONVERT(char(10), DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(DD,0, Date),0), 126) as DateOnly
,ID
Into #Temp
From Table

Select Distinct (Date)
,ID
From #Temp
```

further informations: [Getting the Date Portion of a SQL Server Datetime field](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/SQL/SQLTip2.asp)

**hope this helps!**

Comment: Are you sure that this would return date with delimiter between date parts?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server 2008 - you can cast DateTime column to a built in `Date` type , otherwise to get rid of time you should cast to `VARCHAR()` only day/month/year parts and then convert back to `datetime` so time part would be zeroed:

```
declare @dates table(id int, dt datetime)
INSERT INTO @dates VALUES(1, '2011-10-01 23:57:49')
INSERT INTO @dates VALUES(2, '2011-10-02 23:57:59')
INSERT INTO @dates VALUES(2, '2011-10-02 23:57:39')

SELECT stripped.id, stripped.dateOnly 
FROM
(
   -- this will return dates with zeroed time part 2011-10-01 00:00:00.000
   SELECT id,
          CONVERT(datetime,
          CAST(YEAR(dt) as VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
          CAST(MONTH(dt) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + 
          CAST(DAY(dt) AS VARCHAR(2))) as dateOnly
   FROM @dates
) stripped
GROUP BY stripped.id, stripped.dateOnly
```