# Select Unique/distinct entries during timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my Table layout for VMs in our dc. Every hour we collect metrics, but want to prevent hickups where a poll is done twice and then end up with double information for a given hour.

Below is my table

```
VM_Name              NUM_VCPU   POWER_STATE MEMORY_MB   IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
FERNANDO TEST 2012      4           1         16384      2017-01-10 10:13:42.353
FERNANDO TEST 2012 R2   4           0          8192      2017-01-10 10:13:42.353
```

Before is the query I am using to get the above information

```
SELECT Count([VM_NAME]) as Num_VM
      ,sum([NUM_VCPU]) as SUM_NUM_VCPU
      ,SUM([MEMORY_MB]) as SUM_MEM_MB
      ,SUM([MEMORY_MB])/1024 as SUM_MEM_GB
      ,dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0) as IMPORTEDTIMESTAMPROUND       
  FROM VM_DATA
  Where POWER_STATE = 1
  group by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0)
```

And I get

```
 Num_VM SUM_NUM_VCPU    SUM_MEM_MB  SUM_MEM_GB  IMPORTEDTIMESTAMPROUND  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    2         |4        |24576       |24        |2017-01-10 16:00:00.000     
    1         |2        |12288       |12        |2017-01-11 02:00:00.000    
    1         |2        |12288       |12        |2017-01-11 03:00:00.000
```

As you can see at 4PM (2017-01-10 16:00:00.000) there was a test double poll, and now I have double the metrics in place. How Can I adjust my query to get distinct values, I figure will have to do a subquery but not sure where.

Edit for further Clarification.

So  at 2017-01-10 16:00:00.000 I polled twice, now I have duplicate records in there. I need to Select distinct vm_name and distinct timesstmap to remove the duplicates , and then count all the vms, sum up the cpu and memory and group them by the timesatmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case when (count(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0))-count(Distinct(VM_Name))) = 0 then SUM(NUM_VCPU)
    else SUM(NUM_VCPU)/(count(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0))/count(Distinct(VM_Name))) end as SUM_VCPU
```

Ill have to clean this up but what I came up with that worked. It checks the number of distinct count of VM_Names should match the count of the timestamps. If I have more time stamps than distinct Names then I know I have multiple entries for a given time frame. I do some division to the sum to get correct number

I don't know if there is a prettier way to accomplish this, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `avg()`:

```
SELECT Count([VM_NAME]) as Num_VM,
       sum([NUM_VCPU]) as SUM_NUM_VCPU,
       SUM([MEMORY_MB]) as SUM_MEM_MB,
       SUM([MEMORY_MB])/1024 as SUM_MEM_GB,
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0) as IMPORTEDTIMESTAMPROUND       
FROM VM_DATA
Where POWER_STATE = 1
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0);
```

Otherwise . . . just use `row_number()`.  No aggregation seems necessary:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             (partition by year(IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), month(IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), day(IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), datepart(hour, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP)
              order by IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP
             ) as seqnum
      from vm_data d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I edited my OP to add some clarification. AVG doesnt work because I need the sums of CPU and Memory , Count of VMs, for a given hour.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that your records aren't actually duplicates, but appear so because of the timestamp rounding? What happens when you use DISTINCT? I'm assuming it considers the columns before you do any rounding on your timestamp, which would return the same results. I think you need to cast your rounded date as a varchar, then maybe the distinct will recognize it as an actual duplicate.

See: [Returning Distinct Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255857/returning-distinct-dates)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count([VM_NAME]) as Num_VM
  ,sum([NUM_VCPU]) as SUM_NUM_VCPU
  ,SUM([MEMORY_MB]) as SUM_MEM_MB
  ,SUM([MEMORY_MB])/1024 as SUM_MEM_GB
  ,CONVERT(char(10), dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0), 126) as IMPORTEDTIMESTAMPROUND       
FROM VM_DATA
Where POWER_STATE = 1
group by CONVERT(char(10), dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, IMPORTEDTIMESTAMP), 0), 126)
```

Comment: see if my edit makes any sense/does anything to help